# Adobe Air Local FLV Playback

Tags: apache-flex, flv, drm

I'd like to distribute FLV files from my website, however I want a level of DRM control over the files. So far, I've been able to modify the FLV files to contain a 60 character ID at the very front of the file, but I can't figure out how to get AIR to extract the ID and therefore play the file. All I can figure out is using NetStream, but that won't let me skip 60 bytes, and so it thinks the FLV is invalid.

Any ideas?

Thanks,

Mike Christopher

Comment: I'm assuming you saw this? http://help.adobe.com/en_US/AIR/1.5/devappshtml/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7cdb.html - no idea if it works or not... I haven't even dealt with any video in AIR.

Comment: I did see that, however I'm not using (and don't want to) the AIR DRM system, so none of those functions apply.

Answer (score 0):

While this is not the answer you are looking for, and because I'm not running down some tech puzzle rabbit hole trying to help you figure out if you want to [hammer in a nail with a glass bottle or a shoe](http://weblogs.asp.net/alex_papadimoulis/archive/2005/05/25/408925.aspx), I'll probably get down-voted to all hell - but I feel a need to respond thus:

Maybe the problem is that you're relying on DRM to solve a business model issue. I'm assuming you are trying to ensure that someone doesn't pirate your videos and/or access them without paying. (please let me know if this is assumption is incorrect)

[TechDirt](http://www.techdirt.com/) has a number of posts relating to the issues of relying on DRM, and even if they didn't you have to have noticed that no DRM scheme ends up being successful for a meaningful amount of time. Odds are, most of those people wouldn't have bought it anyway. Maybe you need to look at ways of turning that pirated content into an effective way of attracting new customers.

Not knowing the particulars makes it kind of hard to give a specific answer, but even if you don't pursue it here, it would be worth setting up a case with the Insight Community over at TechDirt. Just a thought.

Comment: I understand where you're coming from. In fact, I'm not using DRM for the sake of preventing piracy but rather to insure that the content is still allowed to be played. Basically, the site I'm working on allows user-uploaded videos and I want to make sure that if a user takes the video down, anyone that downloaded the video won't be able to play it. I know that anyone with a hex editor could go in and delete the first 60 bytes from the file and be able to play it, but 99% of the users won't know how to do that, which is fine for this application.